# Disable password length/complexity in Raring

Tags: 13.04, password

I just made a VM of 13.04. In the installer I could make a short password for the initial account (being chided appropriately).  Now I want another test account but the passwd utility prevents me from doing short/simple passwords.

I have tried `sudo passwd test1` to set a simple password without success.

I have also tried changing the line in `/etc/pam.d/common-password` to:
`"password [success=1 default=ignroe] pam_unix.so sha512"`

But it still appears to be doing the obscure or similar test.

I appreciate having these sort of checks in general, but not when they lack any sort of workaround (even for root).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Odds are your username is not `test1`
`sudo passwd $USER` would change your password
That will break something if you have encrypted your home folder, if I remember correctly